# Not able to get value from drop down list, c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, drop-down-menu

In page load I'm loading a drop down list with names from a postgreSQL database, using SQL.
Later in the code I want to save the selected value in the drop down list into a string variable.
That won't happen. What happens is the first value in the list (index 0) always saves, no matter of which I have selected.

Heres is page load (works fine):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=SYS;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;");
     conn.Open();
     NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT name FROM tbl_syv ORDER BY name", conn); 
     NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         ddPersons.Items.Add((string)dr["name"] + " " + " ");
     }
}
```

Here is Button1_Click. I want to save the selected value into string variable **syv**.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string syv = ddPersons.SelectedItem.Text;
    string name = txtName.Text;
    int studentid = 0;

    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=sSYS;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;");
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_student WHERE name = '" + name + "'";
    NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
         studentid = (int)dr["id"];

    }
}
```

I have tried

```
string syv = ddPersons.SelectedItem.Text;
string syv = ddPersons.SelectedItem.Value;
string syv = ddPersons.Text;
string syv = ddPersons.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: try : ddPersons.SelectedValue.ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that ViewState is saving the state of your page. Why don't you include the following line in your Page_Load method:

```
if ( !IsPostBack)
{    
     NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=SYS;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;");
     conn.Open();
     NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT name FROM tbl_syv ORDER BY name", conn); 
     NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
     while (dr.Read())
     {
         ddPersons.Items.Add((string)dr["name"] + " " + " ");
     }
}
```

It will prevent the Page_Load to populate duplicate items every time someone clicks on the button and prevents the ViewState to interfere with the state of your controls.